# How to stop my background image from flickering on page change?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a 3 page website made up of 3 HTML documents all sharing the same CSS stylesheet. Every time I click a button to change the page on my website, the background image flashes briefly. This look terrible and I cannot figure out how to prevent this. Currently I'm loading this site directly through my file explorer (so it's not a server issue) and the background image is only 555kb. Is there possibly a way to keep the image loaded after the first page open?

I also tried compressing my image to half it's size but that didn't help me.

Comment: maybe you could put that image as inline style with image as base64 string. This way you will prevent that reloading request. I assume it it cached next time but still may produce that flickering effect

Comment: Please provide enough code **i.e.** [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.